# relation "pages_page" does not exist

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create an ideas landing page using Django, which will allow me to post pages and collect email addresses. Right, my app is up and everything is working fine when I run:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

or

```
heroku local web
```

However, when I try to deploy to Heroku and run;

```
heroku run python manage.py loaddata pages.json
```

I'm getting an error I cannot seem to decipher or fix:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "show_nav" of relation "pages_page" does not exist
LINE 17:       </div>', "show_nav" = true, "nav_color" = '#820000', "...
                        ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 305, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 356, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 64, in handle
    self.loaddata(fixture_labels)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 104, in loaddata
    self.load_label(fixture_label)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 167, in load_label
    obj.save(using=self.using)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 201, in save
    models.Model.save_base(self.object, using=using, raw=True, **kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 824, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 889, in _save_table
    forced_update)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 939, in _do_update
    return filtered._update(values) > 0
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 652, in _update
    return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1148, in execute_sql
    cursor = super(SQLUpdateCompiler, self).execute_sql(result_type)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 835, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: Problem installing fixture '/app/pages.json': Could not load pages.Page(pk=1): column "show_nav" of relation "pages_page" does not exist
LINE 17:       </div>', "show_nav" = true, "nav_color" = '#820000', "...
```

I believe this must be related to my models.py page:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError 
# Create your models here.

LAYOUT_CHOICES = (
    ('standard', 'Standard'),
    ('stacked', 'Stacked'),
)

def layout_validator(value):
    if value[0] != "#":
        raise ValidationError("Must start with #")
    if len(value) == 4 or len(value) == 7:
        return value
    raise ValidationError("Incorrect length")

class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=225)
    title_description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    title_btn = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Join')
    title_btn_url = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    show_nav = models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text='Show Navigation Bar?')
    nav_color = models.CharField(max_length=7, default='#000000')
    layout = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=LAYOUT_CHOICES, default='standard')
    video_embed = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I've tried to deleting pages.json and starting from scratch. I tried making fresh migrations. If anybody has any idea what this "relation "pages_page" does not exist" error could be help would be much appreciated?

Comment: have you run `migrate`? seems like field `show_nav` didn't exist.

Comment: I did run [python manage.py migrate] with no problems. The problem is when I deploy to heroku. Based on your comment, I decide to try to completely remove [show_nav] from [model.py]. I ran [python manage.py makemigrations] and [python manage.py migrate] with no problems, and the site reflected the changes on the local host just fine. However, when I ran [git push heroku master && heroku run python manage.py migrate], I got the same error (as If I did not remove [show_nav].

Comment: Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, newsletter, pages, sessions
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying pages.0002_remove_page_show_nav...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "show_nav" of relation "pages_page" does not exist